# How to make a button in HTML which decrement a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to decrement the variable Stock by 1 each time I click the button but it's not working. The value on the website stays the same no matter how many times I click the button:

```js
var Stock = 10;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = Stock;
}

function ButtonFunction() {
  Stock--;

}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction">

  <button onclick="ButtonFunction()">ClickMe</button>

  <h1>"The value for Stock is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>

</body>
```

Comment: myFunction() is never called after the body onload so #myText is never updated. Add a console.log() line to the top of  myFunction, and then check the console in browser developer tools, then you'll see more of what happens. Or use the browser developer tools JS debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function only changes the value of the `Stock` variable.

It doesn't change the value of `document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML` which only gets changed when you call `myFunction` (something you never do).

---

You need to:

- Actually call `myFunction` when the document loads
- Call it again whenever you change the variable.

```js
let stock = 10;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = stock;
}

function buttonFunction() {
  stock--;
  myFunction();
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", buttonFunction);

addEventListener("load", myFunction);
```

```html
<button>ClickMe</button>

<h1>"The value for Stock is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>
```

---

Also note that by convention, variable names which start with a capital letter are reserved for classes and constructor functions in JS, so rename your variables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable is being decremented, but the inner text of the span is not then updated.
Try calling myfunction() after each click ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things going on here. The one I think you're primarily interested in has been answered by Quentin. Others however remain and are (I think) far better habits to get into than variable naming conventions.

0. Inline event handlers = bad. Events that can be removed or supplemented = good. Use attachEventListener for the most control.
1. Functions with names that offer nothing are a pain. Names are the most helpful when they're descriptive.
2. Functions that change and display a variable can be traps. It's often better to have a third function which calls both a function to change something and another function to display it.

Here's yet another approach:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  displayStock();
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onButtonPressed, false);
}

var unitsOfStock = 10;

function displayStock() {
  document.getElementById('myText').textContent = unitsOfStock;
  if (unitsOfStock == 1)
    document.getElementById('plural').textContent = '';
  else
    document.getElementById('plural').textContent = 's';
}

function decreaseStock() {
  unitsOfStock--;
}

function onButtonPressed() {
  decreaseStock();
  displayStock();
}
```

```html
<button>ClickMe</button>
<h1>The value for Stock is: <span id="myText"></span> unit<span id='plural'></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Stock = 10;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = Stock;
}

function ButtonFunction() {
  Stock--;
  myFunction();
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

  <button onclick="ButtonFunction()">ClickMe</button>

  <h1>"The value for Stock is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope it helps you. You have to call myFunction to show the new value of Stock variable in myText id in your click handler ButtonFunction().

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   

        <head>
          <script>
              var Stock = 10;
            function myFunction() {
              document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = Stock;
            }
            function ButtonFunction() {
                Stock--;
                myFunction();
            }
          </script>
        </head>
        
        <body onload="myFunction" >

            <button onclick="ButtonFunction()">ClickMe</button>
        
          <h1>"The value for Stock is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>
        
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: guys thanks for your help but i need to show  the initiated value of stock first then whenever i click the button it decrements

Comment: You have to say what exactly you want!

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you click the 'Click me' button, ButtonFunction() will be called. and `document.getElementById("myText")` get find the html element with the id myText and reference itself to the html element. `innerHTML` will allow you to place your html code inside it and `innerText` allows you to put your text the html element with an id of `myText`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
          <script>
              var Stock = 10;
            function ButtonFunction() {
                Stock--;
                document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = Stock;
            }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button onclick="ButtonFunction()">ClickMe</button>
          <h1>"The value for Stock is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Place the description on the answer to avoid getting downvoted by others